# Angular 8 Material Chips ignore shift + keys in matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes

Tags: angular-material2

I´m trying to set ";" as separator key with matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes. I used SEMICOLON and FF_SEMICOLON values of @angular/cdk/keycodes

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tg6yjw

[image]

With my keyboard I need to press "," + SHIFT to set the ";" char.

In angular material chips code I found this method:

```
 _isSeparatorKey(event) {
    if (hasModifierKey(event)) {
        return false;
    }

    const separators = this.separatorKeyCodes;
    const keyCode = event.keyCode;

    return Array.isArray(separators) ? separators.indexOf(keyCode) > -1 : separators.has(keyCode);
}
```

The hasModifierKey method filter any key with shift. Is the right behavior? If remove this method works fine.